# Can't edit osm_roads in udig

Tags: postgis, road, udig

There is a PostGIS database that has a road network imported from Open Street Map, stored in osm_roads table.

For the testing purposes I need to change some road geometry there. I tried to edit it with uDig Version: 1.4.0b. When I select the layer with osm_roads, I don't see any 'edit' buttons; the only buttons I see are 'create arc', but after drawing the arc it disappears, so I can't edit the road network anyway.

Please advise what I should configure to make this changes possible. What is the most likely reason why uDig doesn't allow to edit the road layer?